# Adding animate (slide from left/right etc.) on page load

Tags: jquery, onload, effect

I want to add some animation when the page loads. I tried a couple times but wasn't successful. Could you help me with a jquery hack?

**HTML & Jquery** part:

```
    <div class="MainPozEstate"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/mrk-sng.png" alt="Acarkent Markavilla"/></a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
            $( ".MainPozEstate a" ).mouseover( function() {
                $( this ).children( "img" ).stop( true, true ).animate({
                    opacity: 0.6
                }, 200, "swing", function() {
                    $( this ).animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 400 );
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**CSS** lines:

```
.MainPozEstate {float:left;width:980px;margin:0px auto;padding-top:30px;text-align:center;}
.MainPozEstate img {border:none;margin:0px auto;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like your animation is triggered on `mouseover` instead of when the page loads. Is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add another effects then maybe do it another call. 
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/w8HzE/2/

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $( ".MainPozEstate a" ).mouseover( function() {
        $( this ).children( "img" ).stop( true, true ).animate({
            opacity: 0.6
        }, 200, "swing", function() {
            $( this ).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 400 );
        });
    });

    //
});

jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    //do your other effects here or just trigger/call mouseover if you want.
    $( ".MainPozEstate a" ).mouseover();
});
```

---

I think your code is working, http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/w8HzE/

Comment: yes i added it. but i want add another animation effect for `MainPozEstate` 'divs image. When you open the page on browser, that image should be start sliding from left and than stop animatig 4 5 sec later.